# constructive Serre classes

Tags: abelian-groups, constructive-mathematics, ac.commutative-algebra, lo.logic

A **Serre class** (of abelian groups) is a class of abelian groups closed under subgroups, quotients, and extensions.  For instance, finitely generated groups and finite groups are both Serre classes.

However, in constructive mathematics, these are no longer examples, at least not with the usual definition of "finite" (= in bijection with $\{0,1,\dots,n\}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$).  In particular, finite sets are not closed under subsets and quotients, so there is no reason that finite groups should be either.

There are other weaker constructive notions of "finite", some of which are described [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/finite+set#Constructivist): subfinite, finitely indexed, subfinitely indexed.  It seems that subfinitely indexed sets — the subquotients of finite sets — are closed under subsets, quotients, and finite products, so that the subfinitely indexed groups should be a Serre class even constructively.  Classically, of course, all subfinitely indexed sets are finite.

My original question was:

> Is there a Serre class of abelian groups in constructive mathematics which reduces classically to the finitely generated ones?

As pointed out by Ingo, this has a trivial and uninteresting answer; the real question is

> Is there a description of the Serre envelope of the class of finitely generated abelian groups which is more explicit than the trivial inductive one?

Comment: Silly answer: define a Serre class to be one closed under *decidable* subgroups and quotients by *decidable* normal subgroups. But you probably need fairly arbitrary quotients, yes?

Comment: I was about to ask something along the lines of Andrej's comment but his formulation is better than mine. I have a hard time imagining what quotients by non-decidable subgroups. What does $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ look like constructively?

Comment: Yeah, I specifically _don't_ want to change the definition of Serre class.  I don't think the application I have in mind (spectral sequences) will yield any decidability conditions.

Comment: Just one word of warning. When working with constructive groups it makes sense to consider *antisubgroups* as well as subgroups.

Comment: So if you take quotients of subgroups of finitely generated groups, how far are we from a Serre class?

Comment: Hmm, well, it should still be true constructively that a quotient of a subgroup of a group is also the subgroup of a quotient, and vice versa, right?  So the class of subquotients of finitely generated groups will be closed under quotients and subgroups.  I'm not so sure about extensions, though.

Comment: Any subclass $\mathcal{C}$ of an abelian category determines a smallest Serre class containing it, by iteratively adding (the zero object and) the object $Y$ for any exact sequence $X \to Y \to Z$ where $X$ and $Z$ are objects of the previous stage. Note the missing zeros; alternatively, one can iteratively add the zero object, subobjects, quotients, and extensions. Anyway, this construction can in particular be performed with the class $\mathcal{C}$ of finitely generated abelian groups. Classically, its closure will coincide with $\mathcal{C}$, as $\mathcal{C}$ is already a Serre class.

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt I suppose that technically answers the question, so if you posted it as an answer I'd accept it.  But I'd prefer something more explicit.

Comment: @Mike Did so. But be encouraged to *not* accept the answer, as the true question is still open. I'm quite interested in a non-cheating answer myself.

Comment: What do you mean by finitely generated anyway? Is a quotient of a free abelian group on a subfinitely indexed set?

Comment: @David I would say a quotient of $\mathbb{Z}^n$, where $n$ is a natural number. Similarly, a finitely presented abelian group is a cokernel of a linear map $\mathbb{Z}^m \to \mathbb{Z}^n$. For those cokernels we constructively have the structure theorem (using the Smith normal form). Also this notion of finitely presented coincides with the general categorical notion of a [compact object in a category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compact+object).

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt okay, thanks!  I updated the question.

Comment: And I agree with Ingo's interpretation of "finitely generated".  Another way to say it would be that it has a finitely indexed subset in terms of which every other element can be written.

Answer (score 4):

Any subclass $\mathcal{C}$ of an abelian category determines a smallest Serre class containing it, by iteratively adding (the zero object and) the object $Y$ for any exact sequence $X \to Y \to Z$ where $X$ and $Z$ are objects of the previous stage. Note the missing zeros at the ends of the sequence; alternatively, one can iteratively add the zero object, subobjects, quotients, and extensions (objects $Y$ such that there is a short exact sequence $0 \to X \to Y \to Z \to 0$ with $X$ and $Z$ previously added).

Anyway, this construction can in particular be performed with the class $\mathcal{C}$ of finitely generated abelian groups. Classically, its closure will coincide with $\mathcal{C}$, as $\mathcal{C}$ is already a Serre class.

**However,** this construction only answers the question in a technical sense, since it describes the sought-after class in rather abstract terms. The construction thus only shows that the question could profitably be reformulated in order to better capture its spirit: "Is there a description of the Serre envelope of the class of finitely generated abelian groups which is more explicit than the trivial inductive one?"